# 'The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.'

Tags: c#, user-interface, ms-access

I'm trying to connect an ms access DB with my C# form, and while am using the click action
an **ERROR** appears

> : 'The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.'

I'm currently using the MS Office 2016 and using the link string:
`string acon = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =C:\Users\kingb\Documents\Persons.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";`

I already installed the ms access engine 2016 X64-bit and the problem is still there.

Comment: If you search for ODBC Data Sources can go under "Drivers", what is the MS Access Driver version listed there?

Comment: The version is wrong.  You have 12.0 and 2016 is 16.0

Comment: I actually forget to say the I changed the version to 16.0 but still got the problem. @jdweng

Comment: The latest version is 2013 @WSC

Comment: What's the actual version number?

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Office Installed on Machine?  ACE automatically gets installed with Office.  If you do not have Office you need to install the runtime version of ACE.  The dll needs to be registered and put in the correct folder.  I suspect you need to 32 bit version.

Comment: I do the version on my machine is 2016 and I already got the file which I'm trying to connect my os is X64-bit. @jdweng

Comment: All of the available versions are 12.0 if you mean that by actual v number.
@WSC

Comment: Yes, but it has to be the version Office is using.

Comment: I changed the platform target from Build settings from **Any CPU** to **x64** and that works I don't have the run time error anymore.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the requirement of Office, install the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)